# How to display the number of items in an array in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and based off the post I have an array of cards, each post will have a different number of cards in this array and I was wondering how I can show the number of cards in the array.

```
$class_cards[]=array('card_count'=>$card_count);
```

The total number of cards in this array will vary by post, so I want to be able to store the number of cards in a variable so I can echo it out later down the page.

Edit: Follow Up Question

I have a follow up to this question, I have a variable which is called `$card_count` which is stored in the array as you can see above. The card count will always be 1 or 2 saying that there is either one version of this card or two versions of this card. If there are two I would need to count that card twice in the overall number how can I do this with `count($class_cards)`?

For example lets say I have a total of 9 cards in that array. The count would turn out as 9, but in that array 6 out of those 9 cards have 2 as their card count, while 3 has 1 as their card count. So the total number of cards should be 15 instead of 9.

Comment: count($class_cards) ?

Comment: mihai, please put that as an answer so the question does not go unanswered :)

Comment: @GavinSimpson thanks for the heads up but it seems someone else took care of this :)

Comment: Lol, Copy someone's comment into an answer. Unlucky.

Comment: @mihai would you be able to help with the follow up question in the edit? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in very simple way like

```
$count_cards = count($class_cards);
```

This will return you the count of the cards.

Comment: I added an edit to the question with a follow up, would you be able to help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi  i think  this  piece  of  code will  help  you  if  i  got  what  you want

```
$count_cards = count($class_cards); // Total number of objects(cards) in an array in this  example  it  is 9 

foreach($class_cards AS $key => $value)
{
   //Assuming the card count as 9  this  loop will  run 9 times 
   if($value['card_count'] == 2)
   {
      $count_cards++; // Adding another card  if the card  count is  2
   }
}
echo $count_cards ; // Total number of cards , Should  echo 15 according to this example
```

Comment: What would be the variable with the stored value of 16 in it then?

Comment: @Greenhoe You said  $card_count will only  be 1 or 2 --> "The card count will always be 1 or 2 saying that there is either one version of this card or two versions of this card."

Comment: Correct, but where is the total card count being added up in? So if we had a total of 9 cards with 6 of them being card count of 2 and 3 being a card count of 1, we should have a total of 15 cards, I need to be able to have 15 in a variable so I can display that later on in the post. I see how you are checking the card count, but not sure I see where the total card count is being stored.

Comment: @Greenhoe edited the answer with  more  comments  hope  you  get  what i am  doing  :)

Comment: It still echo's 9, I think where this is going wrong is I don't see where $card_count variable is used to see if it is 2 cards or 1.

Comment: @Greenhoe $value is the card_count of that pariticular array element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69959/discussion-between-greenhoe-and-user2801966).